# Выборка задач на текущий день в Room

Tags: android, sql, datetime, room

В базе данных Room реализован класс Задача с полями даты/времени.

```java
@ColumnInfo(name = TaskEntry.COLUMN_CREATE_DATE)
@TypeConverters({LocalDateTimeConverter.class, LDateTimeConverter.class})
private LocalDateTime createDate; // дата начала
@ColumnInfo(name = TaskEntry.COLUMN_FINISH_DATE)
@TypeConverters({LocalDateTimeConverter.class, LDateTimeConverter.class})
private LocalDateTime finishDate; // дата завершения
```

Реализована функция для выборки задач, которые доступны сегодня и не завершены, но ее результаты игнорируются и выдается полный список задач без учета диапазона выбранных дат.

```java
@Query("Select * from " + TaskEntry.TABLE_NAME
+ " where (" + TaskEntry.COLUMN_CREATE_DATE + " >= :startDayTime"
+ " or " + TaskEntry.COLUMN_FINISH_DATE + " < :endDayTime)"
+ " and " + TaskEntry.COLUMN_FINISHED + " = 0")
LiveData<List<Task>> getLiveDailyTasks(Long startDayTime, Long endDayTime);
```

Есть подозрение, что такое способ сравнения через конвертацию не работает, но как тогда это можно еще реализовать?

Comment: Пересечение диапазонов детектируется не так. Должно быть "любое начало меньше другого кончала" - т.е. `start1<end2 and start2<end1`.

Comment: В таком случае выборка возвращает 0 задач

Comment: _Есть подозрение, что такое способ сравнения через конвертацию не работает_ - если есть такое подозрение, то где код конвертеров и почему их два на одну колонку и один тип? Какой формат данных в итоге записан в эти колонки? И что передаётся аргументами `startDayTime` и `endDayTime`?